# why is size of text used as source in an SVG feComposite filter affected by the svg element size?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to learn how to use feComposite in SVG, and in particular want to use text as one of the composition sources. Here's an initial sample of what I'm trying to do.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">

  <defs>
    <circle id="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="0" fill="black" />
    <text id="A" x="35" y="70" fill="black" style="font-size:60; font-family:Arial; font-weight:700">8</text>
    
    <filter id="myfilter" width="120%">
      <feImage xlink:href="#circ" result="lay1"/>
      <feImage xlink:href="#A" result="lay2"/>
      <feComposite operator="out" in="lay1" in2="lay2" result="COMP"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <g filter="url(#myfilter)" >
    <use href="#circ"/>
    <use href="#A"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

It gives me this result, as expected:

[image: Text cutting out a circle fill using feComposite]

But, then I wanted to make everything bigger. So, I was going to need to increase the width and height on the svg element. However, when I do that, it causes the text to get smaller. Here's modified SVG, only increasing the height attribute on the svg element:

```html
<svg width="100" height="150">

  <defs>
    <circle id="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="0" fill="black" />
    <text id="A" x="35" y="70" fill="black" style="font-size:60; font-family:Arial; font-weight:700">8</text>
    
    <filter id="myfilter" width="120%">
      <feImage xlink:href="#circ" result="lay1"/>
      <feImage xlink:href="#A" result="lay2"/>
      <feComposite operator="out" in="lay1" in2="lay2" result="COMP"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <g filter="url(#myfilter)" >
    <use href="#circ"/>
    <use href="#A"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

That caused the text content to scale smaller vertically.

[image: Text content of feComposite scaled smaller vertically after increasing height on root svg element]

If I increase the width on the svg element, then the text will scale smaller horizontally:

```html
<svg width="150" height="150">

  <defs>
    <circle id="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="0" fill="black" />
    <text id="A" x="35" y="70" fill="black" style="font-size:60; font-family:Arial; font-weight:700">8</text>
    
    <filter id="myfilter" width="120%">
      <feImage xlink:href="#circ" result="lay1"/>
      <feImage xlink:href="#A" result="lay2"/>
      <feComposite operator="out" in="lay1" in2="lay2" result="COMP"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <g filter="url(#myfilter)" >
    <use href="#circ"/>
    <use href="#A"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

[image]

If instead of increasing the height or width on the svg element, I decrease the values, then the text will scale *larger* in the corresponding direction.

This only happens for text used as the filter source. If I use the same text element without the filter, it's not affected by changes in width/height on the svg root element. For example, in the following, I've modified the previous example by adding a `<use>` element to add another instance of the text (wrapped in a `<g>` with a translation lower on the page):

```html
<svg width="150" height="150">

  <defs>
    <circle id="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="0" fill="black" />
    <text id="A" x="35" y="70" fill="black" style="font-size:60; font-family:Arial; font-weight:700">8</text>
    
    <filter id="myfilter" width="120%">
      <feImage xlink:href="#circ" result="lay1"/>
      <feImage xlink:href="#A" result="lay2"/>
      <feComposite operator="out" in="lay1" in2="lay2" result="COMP"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="40" width="100" height="20" fill="none"/>
  
  <g filter="url(#myfilter)" >
    <use href="#circ"/>
    <use href="#A"/>
  </g>
  
  <g transform="translate(0,70)">
    <use href="#A"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

[image]

What is going on here? Why is the text that's an feComposite source getting scaled based on the svg width/height?

Comment: This seems to be a Chrome bug. Conformant behavior would be to not change the size, as it can be observed when rendering with librsvg or Inkscape. Note that Firefox does not render the filter at all, I think because referencing internal ids is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, SVG filters are prone to screw ups when dimensions and units are unspecified. In this case, the g element is passing bad dimensions to the filter. For example, if you add a "y" coordinate to the first use element (the circle) inside the g element, and adjust its value, the text will shrink and expand.

Everything works fine if you explicitly add dimensions to everything and specify via preserveAspectRatio whether you want the aspect ratio of the input preserved or not. And if you want it preserved, whether you want it to size to the greater (meet) or the smaller (slice) dimension of the input.

Your filter actually discards the contents it was invoked with (its SourceGraphic) - so it doesn't really matter what you have in the g element - it's only using the contents to size the filter region (inconsistently as it turns out). So you may as well just apply a filter to a 100%/100% rect element - which you should size explicitly.

So, if you explicitly specify dimensions - this filter works just fine. I don't know what behavior you're trying to achieve. If you want the content to stay fixed as you expand the SVG element width/height - this is the filter you want.

```html
<svg x="0" y="0" width="100px" height="150px" >

  <defs>
    <circle id="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="0" fill="black" />
    <text id="A" x="35" y="70" fill="black" style="font-size:60; font-family:Arial; font-weight:700">8</text>
    
    <filter id="myfilter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="150">
      <feImage x="0" y="0" height="1" width="1"  xlink:href="#circ" result="lay1"/>
      <feImage x="0" y="0" height="1" width="1"  xlink:href="#A" result="lay2"/>
      <feComposite operator="out" in="lay1" in2="lay2" result="COMP"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <rect filter="url(#myfilter)" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%"/>

</svg>
```

```html
    <svg x="0" y="0" width="200px" height="250px" >

      <defs>
        <circle id="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="0" fill="black" />
        <text id="A" x="35" y="70" fill="black" style="font-size:60; font-family:Arial; font-weight:700">8</text>
        
        <filter id="myfilter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="150">
          <feImage x="0" y="0" height="1" width="1"  xlink:href="#circ" result="lay1"/>
          <feImage x="0" y="0" height="1" width="1"  xlink:href="#A" result="lay2"/>
          <feComposite operator="out" in="lay1" in2="lay2" result="COMP"/>
        </filter>
      </defs>

      <rect filter="url(#myfilter)" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%"/>

    </svg>
```

On the other hand, if you want the content to scale, but keep its aspect ratio, you'll need a filter like this.

```html
<svg x="0" y="0" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >

  <defs>
    <circle id="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="0" fill="black" />
    <text id="A" x="35" y="70" fill="black" style="font-size:60; font-family:Arial; font-weight:700">8</text>
    
    <filter id="myfilter"  primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
      <feImage x="0" y="0" height="1" width="1"  xlink:href="#circ" result="lay1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
      <feImage x="0" y="0" height=".65 " width="1"  xlink:href="#A" result="lay2" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
      <feComposite operator="out" in="lay1" in2="lay2" result="COMP"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <rect filter="url(#myfilter)" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="150"/>

</svg>
```

```html
    <svg x="0" y="0" width="200px" height="250px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >

      <defs>
        <circle id="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="0" fill="black" />
        <text id="A" x="35" y="70" fill="black" style="font-size:60; font-family:Arial; font-weight:700">8</text>
        
        <filter id="myfilter"  primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
          <feImage x="0" y="0" height="1" width="1"  xlink:href="#circ" result="lay1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
          <feImage x="0" y="0" height=".65 " width="1"  xlink:href="#A" result="lay2" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
          <feComposite operator="out" in="lay1" in2="lay2" result="COMP"/>
        </filter>
      </defs>

      <rect filter="url(#myfilter)" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="150"/>

    </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the revisions that work. I still don't fully understand what was going on, and I need to learn more about units/dimensions in SVG. You said, "bad dimensions"; is that just in the sense of unexpected inputs that give rise to non-deterministic results (i.e., subject to different handling by conforming SVG runtime implementations)? Or bad in the sense that the observed behaviour was deterministic and expected per the SVG spec, given the inputs, but not what I wanted?

Comment: Bad dimensions = bug. There are many bugs in SVG Filters. The browser teams fix them very slowly. There are some filter bugs that have been outstanding for 6+ years. SVG text also has a lot of uncompleted features and bugs. So, filters are very powerful, but you have to test everything everywhere and be careful of bugs. And in your case, the filter won't work at all in firefox because it doesn't support fragment inputs to feImage - you have to inline things via data uri.

Comment: Is there an alternative to feImage for me to get inputs for feComposite? I know I can use SourceImage for one, but haven’t figured out how else to get the second.

Comment: "SourceGraphic" - not "SourceImage" :) There are other methods - put both shapes side by side in your SourceGraphic and use feOffset to overlay them and a feFlood that's sized to the result you want to select the end result via feComposite/in. Another method, which works when you have single color shapes - you construct a SourceGraphic putting different shapes in the red, green and blue channels, then use feColorMatrix to separate them out into separate "results" before processing further.

Comment: Right, "SourceGraphic". (Was writing from memory.) 

" the filter won't work at all in firefox because it doesn't support fragment inputs to feImage - you have to inline things via data uri"
How is that done?

Comment: A good place to start: https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/09-svg-data-uris/.

Comment: Another method - for your specific case. Just draw the"8" on top of the circle, like you want, but do it in red - then apply a filter to that group with a feColorMatrix/matrix = "1 0 0 0 0      0 1 0 0 0    0 0 1 0 0    -1 0 0 1 0"  This will convert the alpha channel of whatever is 100% red to transparent.